# Android App mixes up languages, showing multiple languages at the same time

Tags: android, localization

I have a strange behavior while developing an Android app (I am not the original developer, I only just started on updating it):

The app supports two languages (with exactly one strings file for each): German and English.

**When the app runs, some views show English whereas others show German text. At the same time.**

The default language (i.e. `res/values/strings.xml`) is English, the other file is `res/values-ge/strings.xml`. The app runs on a German Android system (v7.0).

So it seems that some views believe they should use the app's default, while others adhere to the user's system language choice.

And it isn't even consistent: While I keep developing the app and update translations in the two strings files, some views, such as the Tab Bar, that initially shows up in German, suddenly appears in English.

I'm not a newbie at programming, having done lots of multi-language apps for other platforms (iOS, for instance), so I sure understand the basic concepts. I am pretty sure I didn't just get the keys in the strings file wrong.

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 on a Mac, in case that matters.

Any ideas why this might be happening? Or how to debug this? Where would I start looking to see why some views use the wrong language, and that even randomly?

**Update** I just realized that "ge" may not be the correct code for German, after all. And, surprisingly, when I rename the "values-ge" folder to "values-de", then I suddenly get the expected German texts in some places. However, in other places, I now get English where I had German before. So, it fixed some views, but broke others. I can't make sense of this.

Also, the date formatter spits out the week-of-day texts in English when I use the "E" code (`new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd.MM.")`): I expect to see "Die, 30.09." but get "Thu, 30.09.". But that's probably worth a separate question.

Comment: The default `strings.xml` is English, but since your system is in German it should always take the German `strings.xml`. do you use Android specific strings, such as `android.R.string.ok`?

Comment: Yes, I do use the R.string accessors, of course. I double check even in the debugger, and changing lines to use string literals instead.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there are several issues I had to solve:

1. The language code "ge" was wrong. Correct is "de".
2. After fixing this by renaming the folder name from "values_ge" to "values_de", and cleaning the project, even deleting the app on the device, it would still get them wrong. Finally, after restarting Android Studio, even that problem fixed itself though.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I thought of is that may be you have some strings missing in the German `string.xml` file. The system will use your system language basically but if it didn't find the needed string in that file it will switch to the default file which is English `string.xml`, so this may be the cause of this behavior.

Comment: No, they are not missing. They are clearly present, along with the other translated strings that DO appear. As I wrote, I do understand those concepts, and I of course checked for these obvious mistakes. It's something more sutble, I am quite sure.